# why product measure 1/N

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Law of eigenvalues $ \lambda_1, \lambda_2, ... , \lambda_{n}$ of an GUE matrix scaled by $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ is given by
$\mathbb{P}((\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ... , \lambda_{n}) \in A ) = \int_{A} \frac{1}{Z_{N}} | \Delta(\lambda)|^2 e^{-N \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\lambda_{i}^2}{2}}d\lambda$

where $ \Delta(x)= \prod_{1\leq i<j\leq N} (x_{i}- x_{j})$ and $Z_{n}$ is normalization constant.
$L_{N}=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \delta_{\lambda_{i}}$ is spectral measure. In one of the paper, it is written
"Note that $L_{N}^2(x=y) = \frac{1}{N}, \mathbb{P}$ almost surely as under Lebesgue measure $ \lambda_{i}'s$ are almost surely distinct."
I don't understand, how we get  $L_{N}^2(x=y) = \frac{1}{N}$, can someone explain thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of the event $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_N$ are all distinct is $1$. On this event, we define the (random) probability measure $L_N$. This measure is supported on  $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_N$, assigning probability $\frac {1}{N}$ to each. Next,  $L^2_{N} = L_N \times L_N$, and so it is a probability measure assigning each pair $(\lambda_i,\lambda_j)$ probability $\frac{1}{N^2}$. Under this measure, the probability of the "diagonal" set, namely $\{(x,y):x=y\}$ is $\frac{1}{N}$, because there are exactly $N$ pairs of the form above on the diagonal (namely $(\lambda_i,\lambda_i)$, $i=1,\dots,n$) and each has probability $\frac{1}{N^2}$.

Comment: yes, I did something like this, but yet wondering how the term "under lebesgue measure, $\lambda's$ are almost surely distinct being used?

Comment: What is the underlying probability space? The GUE ensemble has a  continuous and  strictly positive density with respect to  the Lebesgue measure on ${\mathbb R}^{n(n+1)/2}$, and so the probability measure and Lebesgue measure have the same null events.